# Getting arraylist value from Arraylist<Hashmap>from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am currently working inGoogle maps project, where I get lsit of latitude and longitude from mysql table and stored it in Arraylist containing hashmap.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

I want to get the arraylist value in my post execute method,but it retrives the last index value but not whole list values,

This is my async task code,

```
    class VehiclePath extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                  cDialog = new ProgressDialog(HistoryTrack.this);
                  cDialog.setMessage("Fetching Vehicle Details");
                  cDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                  cDialog.setCancelable(false);
                  cDialog.show();
            }



                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("org_id", LoginActivity.orgid));
                     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vechicle_reg_no", vehicle_reg_numb));
                     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "2014-04-23"));
                     System.out.println("vehicle date no.fdfsd ."+checkdate);
                    // params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("org_id", LoginActivity.orgid));

                     jArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(vehiclehistorysurll, "POST", params1);

                    //Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+jArray+"]");

                    try
                    {
                        if(jArray != null){

                        JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(TAG_SRES);
                        //Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+c+"]");
                        user = c.getJSONArray(TAG_VEHICLE_ARRAY);
                        Log.i("tagconvertstr1", "["+user+"]");

                        for(int i=0;i<user.length();i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("forloop i valuie"+i);
                            JSONObject c1 = user.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject c2 = c1.getJSONObject(TAG_SRES);




                            vehicle_reg_numb = c2.getString(TAG_Vechicle_REG);
                            latitude= c2.getString(TAG_Latitude);
                             longitude = c2.getString(TAG_Longitude);
                            speed = c2.getString(TAG_Speed);
                            exceed_speed_limit=c2.getString(TAG_Exceed_Speed);
                            bus_tracking_timestamp = c2.getString(TAG_bus_tracking_timestamp);
                            address=c2.getString(TAG_address);
                             map.put(TAG_Latitude,latitude);
                             map.put(TAG_Longitude,longitude);
                             map.put(TAG_Speed, speed);
                             map.put(TAG_address, address);


                            vehiclehistory.add(i,map);

                            System.out.println("Values for vehiclehistory list"+vehiclehistory.get(i));
                             System.out.println("size of arraylist::"+vehiclehistory.size());

                        }

                        }

                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cDialog.dismiss();
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                     super.onPostExecute(file_url);
                     cDialog.dismiss();
                     System.out.println("size of arraylist::"+vehiclehistory.size());
                     for(int i=0;i<vehiclehistory.size();i++){
                         System.out.println(vehiclehistory.get(i));
                     }
                     for (int i = 0; i < vehiclehistory.size(); i++) {
                         System.out.println("i value"+i);
                         LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Latitude)), Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Longitude)));
                         System.out.println("pin location"+pinLocation);
                         //  LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(vehiclehistory.get(i), vehiclehistory.get(i));
                    // LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i), Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i));
                        // LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(vehiclehistory1.get(i).latitude, vehiclehistory1.get(i).longitude);
                         String titlevalue=vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_address)+vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Speed);
                         Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                                 position(pinLocation).title(titlevalue));

                         System.out.println("titlevalue of respective pinlocation"+titlevalue);


                     }



            }   

}
```

This is the code where I am trying to get arraylist values in my postexecute,

```
     for (int i = 0; i < vehiclehistory.size(); i++) {
                         System.out.println("i value"+i);
                         LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Latitude)), Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Longitude)));
                         System.out.println("pin location"+pinLocation);
         }
```

I don't know how to get all the arraylist values to set marker in map.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is asyntask code???

Comment: @PankajKumar I posted my asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 List<HashMap<String,String>> listMap=new ArrayList<>();
    for (HashMap<String,String> i:listMap) {
       // access HashMap element
        System.out.println(i.get("key"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it directly by using following code, you just need to access last index of your array.

```
LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(i).get(TAG_Latitude)), Double.parseDouble(vehiclehistory.get(vehiclehistory.size()).get(TAG_Longitude)));
```

Comment: For example I ahve arraylist of size 7,All index values are same like the last index i.e.,6...Why I cannot get the rest of array list values

Comment: Dear you put it in post execution that mean after completion of code lastly it will execute that think it mean it have only last access value in it, so if you want diff. values in it that you have to put inside of doInBackground method and if you want to use that array value out side then you need to use PublishProcess within it.    for your reference this is the link to example [PublishProcess in DoInBackground](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

Comment: just code like following

<pre><code>

public String LangArray[] array;

//.......code..........//

doInBackground()
{
   //...code......

    for loop
    {
       array[i] = your latitude;
    }
    publishProgress(array);
}

 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... array) 
{
   super.onProgressUpdate(array);
   _percentField.setText(array[0]+" ");
   _percentField.setTextSize(array[1]+" ");
    ..
    ..
  }

onPostExecute()
{
     //do same heare also
    _percentField.setText(array[6]+" ");
}